# PHP : DOM parsing + array comparing error

Tags: php

As the title says, I have problems with parsing and comparing.

I'm new to the PHP scene, so I googled the things that can help my case, and just smashed them together in my code, removing others that doesn't seem to help.

```
<?php
//$userurl = $_POST["link"];
//$url = 'https://'.$userurl;
$doc= new DOMDocument();
$doc-> loadHTMLfile('https://shibmax.x10host.com/grpbot/swearlist.html');
$contents = $doc->getElementByTagName('body')->item(0);
$swear= Array("F**K","F**k","f**k","S**T","S**t","s**t","B**H","B***h","b***h");
$pregDOM = preg_split("/[\s,]*\\\"([^\\\"]+)\\\"[\s,]*|" . "[\s,]*'([^']+)'[\s,]*|" . "[\s,]+/", $contents, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$swearlist = array_search($swear, $pregDOM, true);
$intersect = array_intersect($pregDOM, $swear);
echo($intersect);
echo($swearlist);
?>
```

The script shows a blank page, nothing else, although I tested it with a link to an html file full of cursing. I tried adding some of my research results (here in Stack Overflow) and still doesn't work. I once tried using Firebug on it, and Firebug gave me a "500 Internal Server Error".

Note, I used asterisks for the $swear array because I don't think that's allowed here. The actual php script contains no asterisks for the array.

EDIT : Error Check returned this :

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol in /home/shibmaxx/public_html/grpbot/scanpage.php on line 5
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/shibmaxx/public_html/grpbot/scanpage.php on line 5
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(https://shibmax.x10host.com/grpbot/swearlist.html): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/shibmaxx/public_html/grpbot/scanpage.php on line 5
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://shibmax.x10host.com/grpbot/swearlist.html" in /home/shibmaxx/public_html/grpbot/scanpage.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementByTagName() in /home/shibmaxx/public_html/grpbot/scanpage.php on line 6

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to turn on `display_error();` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` if the site is blank. Most likely there's a fatal error somewhere.

Comment: You're using `$pregDOM` before you have defined it.

Comment: @jeroen, didn't know ordering mattered. Gonna give it a go.

Comment: The same for `$url` by the way.

Comment: @Jan, got some weird errors.